# How to execute a python script over a file when double clicking on it in ubuntu

Tags: python, file, ubuntu

I have a python script that can open a particular kind of a file. It is an SPE file, opened using with the spe2py library (https://pypi.org/project/spe2py/). 
I'd like, when I double click on a file of that kind, to launch the script passing to it the path of the file where I clicked. In this way my script could show the content of that file. How could I do to do that?
I am using Linux, Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks,

Comment: in file manager Nemo/Nautilus/Caja you can right click on file and select default program to open files with this extension.

Comment: In Nautilus is only possible to choose between reconnected programs, so I had to create the myapplication.desktop file before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Linux Mint` which is based on `Ubuntu` but it uses `MATE` (desktop environment) with file manager `Caja` (previously `Nemo/Nautilus`) so last point (5) can be different on `Ubuntu` or other `Linux`.

---

You need few things:

1. script has to use `sys.argv` to get selected filename
2. you have to add `shebang` in  first line of script so system will know to use Python to run this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

3. you have to set it executable so system will use `shebang` to run it (and you don't have to use `python script.py`)

```
chmod +x script.py
```

4. you could put script in folder which is in `PATH` so system can run it in any folder without using full path to script. On `PATH` could be folder `~/bin` for your scripts - so you can put script in this folder.
5. in file manager `Nemo/Nautilus/Caja` you can right click on SPE file to see menu - there should be `"Open with ... > Other program"` and you can set your script. You can use full path if you didn't put script in folder from `PATH`. If you use different file manager then you will have to search similar option

`Nemo/Nautilus/Caja` also sets variables with names of selected/highlighted files so you can run script with all files at once.

```
CAJA_SCRIPT_NEXT_PANE_SELECTED_URIS
CAJA_SCRIPT_NEXT_PANE_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
CAJA_SCRIPT_NEXT_PANE_CURRENT_URI
CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS
CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
CAJA_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
```

In script they should be avaliable

```
import os

print( os.environ['CAJA_SCRIPT_NEXT_PANE_SELECTED_URIS'] )
```

or safer if variable doesn't exists

```
import os

print( os.environ.get('CAJA_SCRIPT_NEXT_PANE_SELECTED_URIS') )
```

---

**EDIT: 2021.08.05**

Currently `Python 3` is main used version and on some systems it may need `python3` instead of `python` in `shebang` to work with `Python 3`

Comment: Thanks, I had only to do a change. It was not possible to associate the file via the graphical interface "Open with", so I had to create a "myapplication.desktop" file in /usr/share/applications and to associate to it the correct mime type (I found the mime type in the file properties and I used as a model another mime file I found).
I've not still tested to open more files at once, but I will.

Comment: I use Linux Mint which is based on Ubuntu but it uses MATE ( desktop environment) with `Caja` (previously `Nemo/Nautilus`). Different Linux versions may use different file managers and they may need different methods in point 5.

Comment: Use python3 in shebang to avoid python 2

Comment: @PetrL. you are right. This question and answer is 2 years old and it was created probably when Pyton 2 was still main version :)

Comment: @furas I see it now, thanks. Maybe edit the shebang itself though

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to run your python script using bash script program.

You can make your bash script like this:

> Blockquote

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 python_script.py
```

Save this text file with .sh extension

Comment: you don't need bash script for this. You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python` directly in `script.py` and set `chmod +x script.py` and then `script.py` will run like any other program or bash's script. But it still will not use this script when you click on SPE file.

Comment: @furas this is actually a good answer for those who are seeking to use bash file in specific, however to make your answer better you should also write ``` chmod +x script.sh``` to make your script executable. and add the way on how to open the script with double-click